# Microsoft Graph getting Sharepoint main sites

Tags: javascript, api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible with Microsoft Graph to retrieve the main sites without retrieving the subsites?
I am using the following URL to retrieve these sites:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

The problem is it also retrieves the subsites.
At the moment I bypass this problem by filtering out the items that do not have a root object {} returned:
root object:
[image: root object].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this endpoint :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=contentclass:STS_Site
```